# Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :failed loading cafile stream:

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to send an email in laravel 8 but I keep getting this response **Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :failed loading cafile stream: `/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem'**

Answer (score 1):

I did find a solution to this, simply run this on your terminal

> brew reinstall openssl@1.1